# How to test if a variable holds a lambda-function?

Tags: r, lambda, formula, rlang

I'm building a function where the main argument can be various things, e.g. a formula, a function or a lambda-function and it has to handle things accordingly.

```
library(rlang)
my_func=function(x){
    if(is_function(x))
        return("X is a function")
    else if(is_lambda(x))
        return("X is a lambda")
    else if(is_formula(x))
        return("X is a formula")
    else 
        return("X is something else")
}
my_func(x=is.numeric) #function
my_func(x=A~B) #formula
my_func(x=~is.numeric(.x)) #formula too :'(
my_func(x="foo") #something else
```

As you can see, `rlang::is_lambda` did not recognize the lambda-function. In the help file example, they use `as_function` first (`is_lambda(as_function(x))`), but this throws a conversion error when `x` is not a lambda-function-formula. I'd rather not use `trycatch` if possible, as I find it sometimes leads to unreadable code and hidden bugs.

How can I test this case simply?

Comment: @Brian As I wrote, `rlang::as_function` throws a conversion error when `x` is not a lambda-function-formula. This would make the second example fail with an error.

Comment: Oh, I misread that, you're right. I assumed you wanted it to exclude non-function-like arguments. How will your function work when passed a two-sided formula? Maybe this is something the downstream logic needs alteration for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Allan's answer works fine, I decided to stick to what `rlang` was doing.

If you take a look at `View(rlang::as_function)`, you'll see that it aborts only `if (length(x) > 2)`.

Therefore, my code can be written as:

```
library(rlang)
my_func=function(x){
  if(is_function(x))
    return("X is a function")
  else if(is_formula(x)){
    if(length(x) > 2)
      return("X is a formula")
    else if(is_lambda(as_function(x)))
      return("X is a lambda")
  }
  return("X is something else")
}
```

This will return the expected output every time.

Answer (score 1):

You could deparse the formula and test whether its first character is a tilde. This will mean any formula without a left hand side that could be coerced to a lambda will be recognised as such, but I'm guessing that is the desired behaviour anyway.

```r
library(rlang)

my_func=function(x){
    if(is_function(x))
        return("X is a function")
    else if(is_formula(x)){
        if(substr(deparse(x), 1, 1) ==  "~"){
            if(is_lambda(as_function(x))) 
                return("X is a lambda")
        }
        return("X is a formula")
    }
    else 
        return("X is something else")
}

my_func(x=is.numeric)
#> [1] "X is a function"
my_func(x=A~B) 
#> [1] "X is a formula"
my_func(x=~is.numeric(.x)) 
#> [1] "X is a lambda"
my_func(x="foo") 
#> [1] "X is something else"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Finally, I found out that `as_function` check if `length(x) > 2` before returning an error. I don't know if this covers all eventualities but I guess I will not do better than `rlang`. But your solution works as well.